# I'm trying to import united_states.osm into Spatialite and spatialite_osm_net just quits with no error

Tags: spatialite

When I try to run spatialite_osm_net using united_states.osm as input, the program simply stops after Windows presents a pop-up saying the program ended with an error.

No other information is presented.  The failure occurs in the first phase of spatialite_os_net processing after about 3 hours of processing.

I merged the downloads from cloudmade and unzipped the combined .bz2 file.

I created the output DB with spatialite_gui.

The program level is 3.0.0.

There is more than 250GB of space on the disk and wen te failure occurs the output db is only 7GB.

Has anyone ever successfully done this?

Regards,
Jim

Comment: "I merged the downloads from cloudmade and unzipped the combined .bz2 file." sounds like there are two headers in the file and quits when it hits the second unexpected one.

Comment: There was some follow-on discussion on the SpatiaLite mailing list - not conclusive though: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/spatialite-users/0-chM2iy82Q/vAX8a1qLI5IJ